# Release Management for Visual Studio - Release Not Triggered

Tags: visual-studio, release-management, ms-release-management

Trying to setup automated releases using Release Management for Visual Studio 2013. Process works when manually creating a release in RM Client.

When queuing a new build in Visual Studio, build succeeds, but release never displays in RM.

"Release Build" is set to "True" in Build Template.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build template, "Configuration to Release" was set to "Release - Any CPU". After removing, the Release build process was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an agent-based release template, the release management client has to be installed and configured on your **build agent**.

If you're using a vNext release template, the release build process template will not work. You'll have to customize it to use the [REST API that was added in Update 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/10/10/trigger-release-from-build-with-release-management-for-visual-studio-2013-update-3.aspx).

Comment: If you're referring to the TFS Build Agent, RM Client is installed on the same server, and release still does not start after build.

Comment: @user2966445 In that case, could you provide the detailed build log and what version of Release Management you're using, as well as what version of the release build process template you're using? There were several issues with the release build process templates prior to the one included in Update 4.

Comment: Release Management for Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, using ReleaseDefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml (TFS 2012). Which specific build log is needed?

Comment: The build log should have a section that shows all of the actions in the build process. At the end of the build, there will (hopefully) be a "release" section with more information you can use for troubleshooting.

Comment: The project builds with no errors, there are no additional steps listed in the log after the build. Build template has "Copy build output to the following drop folder (UNC path...)" instead of "Copy build output to the server". UNC path is actually on a different server where RM Server is installed. Would this cause the issue?

Comment: Figured out the issue: In the build template, "Configuration to Release" was set to "Release - Any CPU". After removing, the Release build process was triggered. 

No idea why this would prevent the release, though.

Answer (score 0):

Other than what @DanielMann correctly said in his answer, there are two important flags to consider:

- In the build template, `Release Build` needs to be set to `True` (as mentioned by the OP)
- The `Can Trigger a Release from a Build?` checkbox must be checked. The checkbox can be found in the Release Management client, in the Properties of a specific Release Template. That's also the section where one can specify the Build Definition to use for the Release.

See the [Trigger a release from a build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181355%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN.